# Rails 3 how to remove the app name in page title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my layout file I have

```
<head>
  <title><%= @title %></title>
</head>
```

And in my show file:

```
<% @title = Item.name %>
```

The problem is that in the page title there is added | Myappname instead of just the Item name

How do I remove the app name in page title?

Comment: All signs point to you having an application.html.erb that you don't think you're using, but you are.

Comment: It is my application layout file I got the <head>
  <title><%= @title %></title>
</head>

Comment: I am not using nifty generators

Comment: Look for Myappname in your app, and where it looks like it is being assigned to something, change it to something else and figure out the source of the problem.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong view file have now removed my app name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `@title` in the controller action instead of view. Instead of defining it in show file, you should define it in show method.

```
def show
  @title = Item.name
  ...
end
```

This is because, the show file is evaluated after rendering the layout application.html.erb, so defining `@title` afterwards in the show view file will not affect the `@tilte` in the application.html layout.

Comment: Good idea I will approve your answer

Answer (score 1):

Layout is evaluated before your show file. That is why `@title = Item.name` doesn't affect to your html page title.

I think you should check this: [Rails: How to change the title of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185965/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-a-page-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

check if there's a filter in your ApplicationController.rb pushing your app name in @title