# Rails 5 show content based on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 application that will have dynamic content in the header based on the current route. I realize that I can get the route and compare it with something like `if(current_page?('/home'))` but is this really the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of initializing your dynamic content in controller's actions. It is the common solution for such things.

#### For example:

html:

```
<title><%= @title %></title>
```

controller:

```
def index
  ...
  @title = 'Hello world'
  ...
end
```

Also, you can initialize dynamic content in Rails views using `content_for` helper method. There is a similar question about this [Rails: How to change the title of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185965/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-a-page-in-rails)

If you are sure that you have to set this content in a different place and based on the current route, I advise you to use `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` parameters, although your solution is not bad too.

Comment: I am in agreement with your solution, I feel like the controller should be concerned with something like this, rather than the view. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `params[:controller]`, `params[:action]` or [current_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) would be better

Answer (score 1):

You can use named routes with current_page?:

```
if(current_page?(posts_path))
```

and

```
if(current_page?(post_path(1))
```

In addition, you can also check the the current path by using `request`
if you're in `root path`

```
request.url
   #=> "http://localhost:3000"

request.path
   #=> "/"
```