# Issue with dynamic page <title></title> in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the guidance set out here: [Rails: How to change the title of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185965/rails-how-to-change-the-title-of-a-page)

I am attempting to use: `<h1><%= content_for(:title, "Title for specific page") %></h1>`

While my page title does update successfully: `<title>Title for specific page</title>`

In my source code the `<h1>` tags are empty: `<h1></h1>`

Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`content_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for) isn't meant to render data 'in place', it returns `nil`. Instead, you can define your title in the controller and reuse it in view, for example:

```
@title = 'Title for specific page'
```

and have in your view:

```
<% content_for :title, @title %>
<h1><%= @title %></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I switched to that approach. I like it more as on some pages I don't render the page title anyway. Thank you